# getCurrentPosition not returning location with airplane Mode ON

Tags: flutter, location, geolocator

Plugin geolocator: ^9.0.1 with flight off mode works well,

Not getting location /throwing any error if flight mode is on. I need to get location even in airplane mode

Kindly suggest changes or other plugin with this feature

Tried also with location plugin same happens

Minimal code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
   Position? pos;
   bool? _isLoading;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Location"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("GOT  location LAt ${pos?.latitude}"),
            Text("GOT  location long ${pos?.longitude}"),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text("Get location"),
              onPressed: () {
                getlocation();
              },
            ),
            _isLoading??false? const CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.green,):const SizedBox.shrink(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

    void getlocation() async {
    LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      LocationPermission _permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (_permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        // getlocation(forward: forward);
      } else if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
        await Geolocator.openLocationSettings();
        // getlocation(forward: forward);
      } else {
        await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
          desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
        ).then((Position position) {
          // forward(position.latitude, position.longitude);
        });
      }
    } else if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      await Geolocator.openLocationSettings();
      // getlocation(forward: forward);
    } else {
      try {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading=true;
        });
        var er=   await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
          desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
        );
        print(er.longitude);
        // forward(er.latitude, er.longitude);
      } on Exception catch (er) {
        print(er.toString());
        setState(() {
          _isLoading=false;
        });
      }
      print('dd');
         await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
      ).then((Position position) {
        print('got loca');
        print('lat ${position.latitude}');
        print('long ${position.longitude}');
        setState(() {
          pos=position;
          _isLoading=false;
        });
        // forward(position.latitude, position.longitude);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't copy-paste the same text several times into your question. That definitely won't attract more people to help you.

Comment: Which device are you testing it on?

Comment: REDMI NOTE 7 PRO @lepsch
Android 10

Comment: Interesting... I've tested your code on a Redmi Note 8 Pro and [it's working even if airplane mode is on](https://imgur.com/GPrQnG3). Maybe it's some configuration on the phone itself but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Ok Thanks for info & time,let me check with configuration settings.@lepsch

Comment: @lepsch , what position are you getting, if the phone is in airplane mode, so that it can't know its own position?

Comment: Ok, I clicked your link now, and I noticed your WiFi seemed to be on... Turn that off and tell us if it still works, plz!

Comment: Hmm... that's it. If I turn off the Wi-Fi the location doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @lepsch, thanks for clarifying that!  And I guess this proves, once again, that even phones can't do magic... 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's the total airplane mode (i.e. without any WiFi or mobile data), the phone is not connected to anything, thus has no way of knowing its own position!

And therefore, it can't tell you its position, either.

Comment: airplane mode with no other connection is on!!

Comment: ...And as I said, that means the phone doesn't KNOW its position... So what exactly do you want from it? The correct error msg? It can't give you its position!